# Simple "magic wand" algorithm for black and white (monochrome) images?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

If one visits a site like VectorStock and types "silhouette" or "man silhouette", one will see a vector image consisting of a white background and the black shapes of many men.

What is the best way to cut out the men from the image, similar to the "magic wand" tool in Photoshop? I imagine this algorithm won't have to be as sophisticated, since we know there are only two colors (black and white) and we want to extract the black images.

I am trying the following (in pseudocode):

```
For each pixel
   --> If pixel is white, continue
   --> Else if black-->add it to a group 
          --> Recursively check all adjacent pixels, and if they are black add it to the calling recursors group (if any, or create a new group)
```

At the end, all  of the black pixels should belong to a group such that every other pixel in the group is connected.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No algorithm accomplishes this task more efficiently than the one you just described. This is what's called the [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

It scans `n` pixels and the recursive search visits each pixel no more than once, for a total running time of `O(n)`. You can't do better than that.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know this was a real algorithm :D. Came up with it on my own!

Comment: Way to go! This is a pretty good algorithm to devise on your own. If I've answered the question to your satisfaction, could you upvote and accept my answer, please?

Comment: Where did you learn about flood fill ? Was it in some textbook, or something you encountered while working ?

Comment: I first encountered it at university in a programming competition. Since then I've used the algorithm several times in game programming.